# two dimensional array - significance of [|[||]|]

Tags: f#

Two functions are defined:

```
let to2DStrArray (inObj : string[][]) = 
    Array2D.init   inObj.Length inObj.[0].Length (fun i j -> inObj.[i].[j])                            

let toTypedList typeFunc (strArray : string[,]) =
    if (Array2D.length1 strArray) = 0 then 
        []
    else
        List.init (Array2D.length1 strArray) typeFunc
```

trying to call them from fsx as follows fails:

```
    let testData = to2DStrArray [|[||]|] 
    let failingCall =   testData
                        |> toTypedList (fun row -> (Double.Parse(testData.[row,0]),
                                    Double.Parse(testData.[row,1])))
```

What is a working/better way to get this code to handle the case of empty 2-dimensional string arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in `toTypeList` function so you don't have to check whether `strArray` is empty or not. It will give an error if you check `inObj.[0].Length` in `to2DStrArray` function when the input array is empty. A safe way to create an Array2D from an array of array is using [array2D operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee620670.aspx):

```
let to2DStrArray (inObj : string[][]) =
    array2D inObj
```

Of course, you have to guarantee that all inner arrays have the same length. And the other function is shortened as follows:

```
let toTypedList typeFunc (strArray : string[,]) =
    List.init (Array2D.length1 strArray) typeFunc
```

*Given your use case, note that* [|[||]|] *is not an empty string[][]; it is an array which consists of only one element which in turn is an empty string array*. Therefore, it causes a problem for the anonymous function you passed to `toTypedList`. Since the two dimensional array has `length2 <= 1` and you accesses two first indices, it results in an index of bound exception. The function could be fixed by returning option values, and you can extract values from option values to use later on:

```
let testData = to2DStrArray [|[||]|] 
let failingCall = testData                    
                  |> toTypedList (fun row -> if Array2D.length2 testData >= 2 then Some (Double.Parse(testData.[row,0]), Double.Parse(testData.[row,1])) else None)
```

Comment: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at FSI_0012.failingCall@46.Invoke(Int32 row) in "this row -> |> toTypedList (fun row -> (Double.Parse(testData.[row,0]),                                     Double.Parse(testData.[row,1]))) "

Comment: @HK_CH: typeFunc isn't actually executed with an empty array of array. You can test with `let testData = to2DStrArray [||] `

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer! I had not appreciated the difference between the array containing one empty array, and the empty array. All clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically you will have another problem as `testdata.[0].Length <> testdata.[1].Length` - unless you know this from somewhere else.  I suspect that the best approach

```
let ysize = (inobj |> Array.maxBy (fun t -> t.Length)).Length
```

I quickly tested this and it seems to work - although it may still fail at the point where you access the array

Comment: indeed I know that the array will not be jagged (so no need to check for the length2 max)